# How to fill tinymce-rails editor with capybara and selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, tinymce, cucumber, capybara

I have trouble with using capybara to test tinymce form. I'm using [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) and have 7 editors in my form. Also I'm using asciimath plugin with tinymce.

Everything works fine, but I'm unable to write tests to fill in tinymce editor.

Here is how my step definition code looks like, very similar to what is described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/ruby-capybara/BxHQjdzrknY/VXCsaDTMPMQJ):

```
within_frame("content_ifr") do
  editor = page.find_by_id('tinymce')
  editor.native.send_keys 'test'
end
```

The problem is when I run the following:

```
editor.native.clear            # works, clear the editor area, I'm testing this with pry
editor.native.send_keys :tab   # works, moves focus to next input
editor.native.send_keys 'test' # returns "", nothing happens, nothing in editor
```

So `clear` and `send_keys :tab` work as expected. But I can't send any string. `send_keys` function is always returning empty string, and nothing happens when I do test using pry.

What is going wrong here? and how can I debug / investigate the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to chrome as described [here](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/09/27/use-chrome-with-cucumber-capybara/) solved my problem.

Obviously the problem is related with a bug in firefox driver.

Still i think it is a valid question for firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your helps Andrey. I saw that page too and decided to switch to chrome after.

Answer (score 9):

I know that this is an old question but I just found it while trying to solve this issue as well.

Although the original question said that he has 7 tinymce's on the same page I think that my solution might work for him too but I do know it will work if there is one tinymce as was my case.

In my request spec I used this:

```
page.execute_script('$(tinymce.editors[0].setContent("my content here"))')
```

The `page.execute_script` with tell it to run the jQuery function.  It then finds the first tincymce editor and sets the content.

Worked like a charm for me.  I think if there are more than one tinymce it can be called by its position.

Comment: This works. A small potential improvement: rather than `tinymce.editors[0]`, I prefer to do something like this: `page.execute_script('tinymce.get("my_element").setContent("updated content");')`. More clear what's happening.

Comment: Not sure if it's unique to me, but I had to also add `page.execute_script("tinymce.get('#{id}').save();")` where id is the textarea id. `save()` pushes the content from tinymce to the hidden textarea.

Answer (score 1):

just came across this problem with RoR and rspec

I managed to solve by doing this:

```
within_frame { page.find_by_id("tinymce").set("new content here") }
```

the `set` method will replace any existing content by the new one

if you want to keep the current content and add things to it, use the `send_keys` method

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to an iframe that contains tinymce textarea input, and than send_keys:

```
# +session+ is an instance of Capybara::Session class
browser = session.driver.browser
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe_id)
editor.native.send_keys(text)
browser.switch_to.default_content
```

Comment: Thanks. But this didn't help. i can navigate in iframes, select editors, clear their input without any problem.. Or even i can send :tab key. My problem is i cant send 'string' in firefox. Also everything is working with chrome now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After a day fighting, my tests finally passed.

The code that I am using is:

```
within_frame("producto_condiciones_ifr") do
  editor = page.find_by_id('tinymce')
  editor.native.send_keys 'filling text'
end
```

The first line is a method of capybara. The parameter passed is the ID of the iframe.

Line #2 is a must.

In line #3 goes the text that you wish to place inside TinyMCE