# fill_in in tinyMce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, tinymce, cucumber

I want to fill in text in a page having Tinymce Editor for functional Automation testing using Cucumber and selenium driver.I am able to open the image dialog but unable to fill in the textfield inside it .i know that TinyMce has an embeded Iframe tag which holds other html.
I have used below steps,but doesnt works.

```
When /^I fill in the xpath "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |xpath, value|
  find(:xpath, xpath).set 'value'
end
```

and

```
When /^I fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |field, value|
  fill_in(field, :with => value)
end
```

i get an error as `Unable to find xpath` PFA of image for refrenece.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should switch to chrome and use the method here: [How to fill tinymce-rails editor with capybara and selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581474/how-to-fill-tinymce-rails-editor-with-capybara-and-selenium)

Looks like firefox has a know bug around this.

Comment: forgot to mention but i am using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me....

```
When ^I enter (.+) in textbox of tinymce iframe having id as (.+)$ do |any_details,tiny_id|
  within_frame("#{tiny_id}") do
    fill_in("image_name", :with =>any_details)
  end  
end
```

Also,to select **entire text in the Editor** for automating ,use this:c

```
When ^I select the entire textarea content in the editor$ do
  evaluate_script("tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), true);")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
When /^I fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |field, value|
  sleep 0.5 until page.evaluate_script("tinyMCE.get('#{field}') !== null")
  js = "tinyMCE.get('#{field}').setContent('#{val}')"
  page.execute_script(js)
end
```

For reference, check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/eoinkelly/69be6c27beb0106aa555)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
page.execute_script('tinymce.get("my_element").setContent("updated content");')
```